# Need bash to separate cat'ed string to separate variables and do a for loop

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split, cat

I need to get a list of files added to a master folder and copy only the new files to the respective backup folders;   The paths to each folder have multiple folders, all named by numbers and only 1 level deep.

```
ie /tester/a/100
   /tester/a/101 ...
```

`diff -r`  returns typically  "**Only in /testing/a/101: 2093_thumb.png**" per line in the diff.txt file generated.

```
NOTE: there is a space after the colon
```

I need to get the **101** from the path and **filename** into separate variables and copy them to the backup folders.

I need to get the lesserfolder var to get **101**  without the colon
and mainfile var to get **2093_thumb.png**  from each line of the diff.txt and do the for loop but I can't seem to get the `$file` to behave. Each time I try testing to echo the variables I get all the wrong results.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 diff_file=/tester/diff.txt
 mainfolder=/testing/a
 bacfolder= /testing/b

 diff -r $mainfolder $bacfolder > $diff_file
 LIST=`cat $diff_file`

 for file in $LIST
  do
    maindir=$file[3]
    lesserfolder=
    mainfile=$file[4]
    # cp $mainfolder/$lesserFolder/$mainfile $bacfolder/$lesserFolder/$mainfile
    echo $maindir $mainfile $lesserfolder
 done
```

If I could just get the `echo` statement working the `cp` would work then too.

Comment: What's wrong with rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
diff_file=/tester/diff.txt
mainfolder=/testing/a
bacfolder= /testing/b

diff -r -q $mainfolder $bacfolder | egrep "^Only in ${mainfolder}" | awk '{print $3,$4}' > $diff_file

cat ${diff_file} | while read foldercolon mainfile ; do
  folderpath=${foldercolon%:}
  lesserFolder=${folderpath#${mainfolder}/}
  cp $mainfolder/$lesserFolder/$mainfile $bacfolder/$lesserFolder/$mainfile
done
```

But it is much more reliable (and much easier!) to use `rsync` for this kind of backup. For example:

```
rsync -a /testing/a/* /testing/b/
```

Comment: You're welcome. Now, unless there's something missing in the answer, could you accept it, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `while read` loop

```
diff -r $mainfolder $bacfolder | while read dummy dummy dir file; do
    echo $dir $file
done
```